# Python: How to easily reference elements in .format()

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

```
print("Small: {} Medium: {} Large: {} Total:{}\n".format(stock[x][0],stock[x][1],stock[x][2],stock[x][0]+stock[x][1]+stock[x][2]))
```

Is there an easier way to write the last element `stock[x][0]+stock[x][1]+stock[x][2]` in reference to the others in the list so I don't have to add it all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be simply done by unpacking list using *stock and sum(stock)

```
stock = [1,2,3]
print ("Small: {} Medium: {} Large: {} Total:{}\n".format(*stock, sum(stock)))
```

Output:

```
Small: 1 Medium: 2 Large: 3 Total:6
```

Comment: This is my preference, because comprehensions are amazing at being succinct while also keeping individual sorting operations grouped tightly together.

Answer (score 3):

You can re write it like this using variables:

```
stockx = stock[x]
a,b,c = stockx[0],stockx[1],stockx[2]

print("Small: {} Medium: {} Large: {} Total:{}\n".format(a,b,c,a+b+c))
```

Answer (score 2):

If `stock[x]` has only the 3 elements you  mentioned, you can use

```
sum(stock[x])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sum`:

```
sum(stock[x])
```